# How to convert teradata recursive query to spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am trying to convert below Teradata SQL to Spark SQL but unable to. Can someone suggest a solution?

```
create multiset table test1 as 
(
   WITH RECURSIVE test1 (col1, col2, col3) AS 
   (
      sel col11, col2, col3 
   from
      test2 root 
   where
      col3 = 1 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      indirect.col11,
      indirect.col2 || ',' || direct.col2 as col2,
      indirect.col3 
   FROM
      test1 direct,
      test2 indirect 
   WHERE
      direct.col1 = indirect.col11 
      and direct.col3 + 1 = indirect.col3 
   )
   sel col1 as col11,
   col2 
from
   test1 QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 
ORDER BY
   col3 DESC) = 1 
)
with data primary index (col11) ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach myself as set out here http://sqlandhadoop.com/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark/ some time ago.

I cannot find my simplified version, but this approach is the only way to do it currently. I assume that in future Spark SQL support will be added for this - although???

On a further note: I have seen myself the requirement to develop KPIs along this while loop approach. I would suggest that the recursive SQL as well as while loop for KPI-generation not be considered a use case for Spark, and, hence to be done in a fully ANSI-compliant database and sqooping of the result into Hadoop - if required.

Comment: Yea i see it could be done using scala. But is there a way to do using the spark sql? Like a work around or something.

Comment: No. That is the whole point. The WITH statement in Spark SQL is limited as of now. No recursion and thus ptocedural approach is required.

Comment: I believe I have answered the question.

Comment: Was able to get it resolved. I created a view as follows :                                  
 
create or replace temporary view 
temp as  
 select col11, col2, idx 
   from
      test2 root 
   where
      col3 = 1 ;
   
create or replace temporary view 
finalTable as  
select col1
    ,concat_ws(',', collect_list(col2)) tools_list
from (select col1, col2 from temp order by col1, col2) as a
group by col1;

Comment: I doubt that a recursive query like connect by as in Oracle would be so simply solved. Not really convinced. Post as your own answer.